# Pandas - how to find a sequence of 6 zero in any row in a data frame, and replace it to NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I find every row in a data frame that contains 6 zero (in adjacent columns),
and then to replace this 6 zero to Nan?

Answer (score 1):

We could torture Numpy functions to get us some clever way to do this.  But it is simpler and likely more efficient to loop with Numba.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit
```

### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 14])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(2, size=(100_000, 20)),
    columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST']
)
```

---

#### Numba

```
@njit
def replace_too_many_zeros(a, k):
    i = [0][:0]
    j = [0][:0]
    for i_, row in enumerate(a):
        count_zeros = 0
        for j_, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == 0:
                count_zeros += 1
            else:
                if count_zeros >= k:
                    j += list(range(j_ - count_zeros, j_))
                    i += [i_] * count_zeros
                count_zeros = 0
    return np.array(i), np.array(j)
```

---

#### Numpy slice assignment

```
a = df.to_numpy()
i, j = replace_too_many_zeros(a, 6)
a[i, j] = np.nan
df.loc[:] = a
```